# scrapy extrat from newspapers to txt

Tags: scrapy

I'm a little bit new to scrapy, and i need to extract some newspapers information for a work, i've tried some tutorial but none of them worked as i expected, the objective is to  a given url, extract the informations about the first 4 ou 5 topics (the inside information when we click the link).
I've tried  to navigate through the links first of all, bit i fail, the output is empty and says 0 crawled pages.

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.dn.pt/pesquisa.html?q=economia%20empresas']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('div.gs-title'):
            yield 
            {
            'title': title.css('a.gs-title::text').extract_first()
            }
```

[the title / link for the first news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVAaW.png)

[the div containing all the news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lid1M.png)

Crawler goes to first link, and extract the information on that link, then goes to second, and extract the informations of the second. like that for the 4 or 5 first news.

Log:

```
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True, 'LOG_FILE': 'output.log'}
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware', 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-05-03 12:46:37 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-05-03 12:46:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dn.pt/pesquisa.html?q=economia%20empresas> (referer: None)
2017-05-03 12:46:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-05-03 12:46:38 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 242,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16289,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 3, 11, 46, 38, 199050),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 3, 11, 46, 37, 873062)}
2017-05-03 12:46:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider &> output.log` commands.

Comment: Please make additions to your question by editing your question directly, not by posting the additions as a question (cleaned this already up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at `http://www.dn.pt/pesquisa.html?q=economia%20empresas` and it seems the content doesn't come with the initial HTML that is captured by scrapy.

Instead the content is downloaded and rendered by subsequent Javascript / AJAX requests which Scrapy doesn't capture out of the box.

**Possible solutions:**

Either you use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to understand how those background requests work and you try to emulate and scrape these background requests directly. (Means more work but the resulting scraper is much faster).

Or you add Splash or a Selenium instance to make them render the Javascript and then scrape the rendered pages directly.